# Why is there an interface field in routing table?

Tags: networking, routing, network-protocols

Imagine that we have an IP-packet, and we need to figure out which interface it should be sent through. There is an `eth0` (for example) corresponding with our packet destination address.

**But what if there is more than one data link layer protocol over `eth0`?**

For example, `Ethernet` and `PPPoE`. How do we figure out which protocol the packet should be using?

Comment: If you included routing table listing in your question you would probably answer it yourself. `route print` on windows, `route` on linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can have more than one link layer on a single interface.

In the case of PPPoE, establishing the PPP connection creates another interface, typically called `ppp0`.  Your routing table entry will point to `ppp0`, *not* to `eth0`.  When a packet is routed to `ppp0`, it's actually handed to the local PPPoE software, not transmitted anywhere.  But then the PPPoE software produces a *new* packet which it transmits via `eth0`.

This is similar to how some VPNs work, by the way.  [OpenVPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN), for example, creates a new interface called either `tun0` or `tap0`, whose "link layer" is the OpenVPN daemon.  Send a packet to one of those, and the daemon encrypts it and puts the ciphertext into a new packet, typically plain UDP, addressed to the remote OpenVPN server.  That packet goes through the routing process and finds its way to a real interface like `eth0`.

(Unlike the VPN example, when PPPoE sends a packet over `eth0`, it doesn't rely on the routing table to route the packet there, because `eth0` is not configured with an IP address and packets can't be routed to it.  Instead, I think it uses a [raw socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket) to send a custom Ethernet frame, addressed to the PPPoE peer's MAC address, that contains a PPP payload, *not* an IP payload.  [RFC 2516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2516) has the details of the protocol.)

Answer (score 0):

There is never more than a single data layer protocol operating over an interface (unless you are doing something very very strange).  Where it looks like there might be, almost always some form of tunneling or encapsulation using is going on - there's usually some other virtual interface "riding on top of it".

"PPPoE" stands for PPP over Ethernet.  THe physical interface eth0 is using Ethernet as the Layer 2 protocol.   PPP is a layer on top of it, handled by a PPPoE daemon.  So the PPP "link layer" packets are ultimately encapsulated in Ethernet frames.

Basically PPPoE works like tunneling/VPN software as @Wyzard says.  Tunnels have a virtual interface on one "side", the de/encapsulation software in the middle, and then the real interface on the other side.

So you'll have an interface such as ppp0 or whatever, which is connected to the PPPoE daemon, and then the PPPoE daemon encapsulates what's coming in on ppp0 and shoves out of eth0.  And vice versa.

One thing to keep in mind is that since Ethernet's MTU is 1500, but 8 bytes of room needs to be made for the PPPoE header, so the MTU of the PPPoE interface becomes 1492.

You don't need to touch eth0 directly since all you want coming out of eth0 is PPPoE packets for your DSL provider.  It's the same general concept for VPNs or IPv6-over-IPv4 tunnels.